# Jesus wept 2 times or more?

Tags: luke

John 11:35 Jesus wept.

Luke 19:41
As he approached Jerusalem and saw the city, he wept over it

Jesus wasn't afraid to cry in the public. Was this common at the time?

Comment: Paul did similarly. _Therefore watch, and remember, that by the space of three years I ceased not to warn every one night and day with tears._ Acts 20:31. (Up-voted +1.) Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom right) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: And that's surprising [because](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0171804)... ? You do realize that there's an entire book in the Bible entitled *Lamentations*, right ?

Comment: Professional mourners were often hired for funerals in bible times, and, yes, it was common: https://www.gotquestions.org/tear-clothes-Bible.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In context of the Tanakh & Gospels, Is it common for men to have wept (Ἐδάκρυσεν) publically?

1. Abraham (Avraham, אַבְרָהָ֔ם) wept (Vekotah, בְכֹּתָֽהּ) for his wife Sarah in Genesis 23:2, after her death.
2. Joseph (Yosef, יוֹסֵ֖ף) wept (Yivekh, יֵּ֥בְךְּ) for his brothers in Genesis 50:17, because they asked for their sins to be forgiven.
3. Jesus (Yeshua, ישׁוּעָ) wept for 'God has helped' a.k.a - Lazarus (Eleazar, אלעזר‎) in John 11:35, because Mary announced Jesus was not there to help Lazarus from dying.

- In context to the loss of loved ones & the forgiveness of sins, the bible demonstrates that weeping is a masculine emotion to display publically.

Does God ever weep in the Tanakh? - Yes.

1. The Word of YHVH tells the prophet Yirmiyahu (יִרְמְיָ֔הוּ) in Jeremiah 14:17 - "And you shall say this word to them: May my eyes run down with tears day and night and not be silent".

- Luke 19:41 alludes to Jeremiah 14:17, while Yeshua wept ( ἔκλαυσεν) over Yerushalem in fulfillment of the Word of YHVH.

Comment: What determines that the tears belong to YHVH and not Jeremiah?

Answer (score 1):

> John 11:35 Jesus wept.

wept.
Ἐδάκρυσεν (Edakrysen)
Verb - Aorist Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's Greek 1145: To **shed tears**, weep. From dakru; to shed tears.

Jesus wept quietly for his friend Lazarus.

> Luke 19:41
> As he approached Jerusalem and saw the city, he wept over it

He wept
ἔκλαυσεν (eklausen)
Verb - Aorist Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's Greek 2799: To weep, weep for, mourn, lament. Of uncertain affinity; to sob, i.e. **Wail aloud**.

Jesus wept aloud for the Holy City and for the Jews.

> Hebrews 5:7
> During the days of **Jesus**' life on earth, he offered up prayers and petitions with fervent **cries** and **tears** to the one who could save him from death, and he was heard because of his reverent submission.

Jesus wasn't afraid to shed tears on multiple occasions unlike today's cinematic tough heroes.

Was it a common happening of people in general at that time?

Jesus arrives at the scene where a girl has died in Matthew 9:23, Young's Literal Translation:

> And Jesus having come to the house of the ruler, and having seen the **minstrels** and the multitude making **tumult**

Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers

> Minstrels are there, with a crowd of real or hired mourners, raising their wailing cries.

It was customary to hire professional musicians and mourners on such occasions. Yes, in those days, people showed mourning publicly with loud sounds. It was a way to cope with the loss of a loved one to reduce the pain of the heart.